# Team Foundation Server Change Source Control Invalid Status

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, disaster-recovery, tfvc

I have a new laptop because the old one is crashed.
On the old laptop I have a Visual Studio solution that is connected to Team Foundation Server and there were a lot of changed made before I could do a check in.

Luckily I made a backup of the complete folder structure inclusive my changes.

Now on my new laptop I installed VS2013 and copied the solution to my harddrive (E: disk). When I open the solution, all the projects are loaded correctly, but there is no connection to TFS.

When I look at "Change Source Control" all the projects have a Invalid status.
I tried to set the workspace correctly but nothing worked so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is easiest solved by:

1. Creating a new workspace, make sure it's a local workspace, on a new location.
2. Get the same version that is your base version using <kbd>Get Specific Version</kbd>
3. Deleting its contents (while retaining the `tf$` folder)
4. Pasting your old solution with updates over the one you just created
5. Perform a <kbd>Get Latest Version</kbd>
6. Resolve any conflicts
7. Check in.

Harder, but which may work without the need to download the whole solution again from source control, from Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt run:

```
tf workspace "Workspacename;Owner" /computer:NEWCOMPUTERNAME
```

After opening your solution you may need to rebind your solution from the Manage Source control window.